# Binding to the list of groups in grouped collections

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, collectionviewsource

Hi I have an `ObservableCollection<Setting>` where `Setting` is described below

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public string SubGroup { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

I want to have two listboxes where the first one contains contains only the list of groups (Group property) while preserving ability to select any group (and launch consequent filtering of settings in the second listbox by selected group of the first one)and the second one contains the full collection of settings grouped by SubGroup property . I'm going to wrap my list of settings into two different `CollectionViewSource` for `ItemsSource` properties of listboxes but in case of the first listbox I can't select any group because it is not actually an element of underlying collection. How can I implement it? I still have to maintain filtered state of groups in the first list box. Sample view is on attached image.

Before filtering

[image]

After filtering

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I want to be able to select groups in the first list box but they are not the items from underlying collection therefore can't be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by having property called `SettingGroups` in my view-model of `ICollectionView` which I get from my observable collection property. I added group description and bound first list box to `SettingGroups.Groups`. Now filtering of underlying collection view works fine so only groups having at least one filtered in setting are displayed in the first listbox